# DRUPAL: how to order the nodes alphabetically in the back-end

Tags: drupal

How can I order the nodes alphabetically in my Drupal back-end ?

I cannot sort the columns by clicking on the headers unfortunately. Should I hack the code or install any plugin ?

Comment: so, according to your answers the only solution is to use view instead of the standard Drupal interface.

Comment: Yes that is the best/simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use views and [views bulk operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to setup a customized admin interface for your nodes where you can run operations like delete, publish etc.

If you just want to make a listing of the nodes, you don't need views bulk operations but can instead use views to make a customized sortable listing.

Comment: The easiest way to replace your admin forms with views, is to use the Admin Views module that comes with version 3 (currently in alpha) of the Admin Menu module (http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu).

Answer (score 0):

plugin = module. Try Views module with Table theme style...